# How to coalesce the repeating sequence of non-alphanumeric symbols into just one in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text that may contain repeating non-alphanumeric sequences, for example:

```
abc\n \n def\n \n kk
```

In this example, the carriage return symbol is followed by the space and it's repeating. I need to leave only one such sequence:

```
abc\n def\n kk
```

The problem is I can't predict which exact symbols the sequence could consist of (it could be space, tab, whatever) so I need some solution (in regex I guess) that finds all such repetitions and replace them with just one.

Other cases:

- sequence of multiple commas
- tab followed by space
- sequence of spaces
- and others.

The solution by @Barmar is almost perfect but for some reason, it doesn't replace all such sequences in this example:

```
\n \n \n \n \n \n aaa \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n bbb \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n aaa \n \n \n  \n  \n  \xa0May 25, 2023 \n\n  \n\n  \n  \n  \n \n \n \n\n                    \n                    ttt\n\n                    \n                 \n \n Read more \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n tt \n          \n\n          \xa0•\xa0©\n          \n          2023\n          \n\n         \n \n          sss \xa0 eee \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n
```

Result:

```
\n aaa \n bbb \n aaa \n \n  \xa0May 25, 2023 \n\n  \n \n \n \n ttt\n \n \n Read more \n tt \n \n \xa0•\xa0©\n          2023\n \n \n  sss \xa0 eee \n
```

Upd. I think the example above is not correct because it's just a result of replacing multiple sequences and as a result, it has them.  Repeated application of regex helps.

Upd 2. When there is a web URL like `https://nomads.com` this script removes one slash from it that is inappropriate. Any fix?

Comment: Are you always looking for "newline followed by whitespace"?

Comment: @TimRoberts No, it can be anything. The only requirement is they are always non-alphanumeric. I updated the question with more cases.

Comment: What should be the replacement result for `,\t \t,` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Nothing I guess because there are no repeating sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capture group to match the first occurrence, and a back-reference to match the repetitions. Then replace it with the captured value.

`\W` matches non-alphanumeric characters.

```
s = 'abc\n \n def\n \n kk'
result = re.sub(r'(\W+?)\1+', r'\1', s)
print(result)
```

Comment: It's almost perfect but for some reason, doesn't replace all the sequences in some cases - please see the example in the post, I've updated it. UPD Okay, I figured out it's just a result of replacing, so the repeated application of regex solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I tested with text containing URLs, it removes a slash from it. How can it be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: You said you wanted to remove repeating non-alphanumeric characters. Slash is not alphanumeric, so `//` will remove the duplicate and become `/`.

Comment: Change `\W` to `[^a-zA-Z0-9/]` so slashes won't be removed. But this means if the string contains `foo/////bar` it will be left alone.